# LINQ2SQL and NHibernate, grouping by calculated columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

In a SQL Server database, I have a table with log entries - `timestamp` and `description`.

I need to get logs occurrence in specified intervals (30minutes).

E.g.:

```
01.01.2015 00:00 - 100
01.01.2015 00:30 - 200
01.01.2015 01:00 - 2
```

and so on...

What I have:

```
var logs = session.Query<Log>;

//... other operations on logs queryable

var intervalInMinutes = 30;
var logsFrequency = logs
    .GroupBy(l => new
    {
        Year = l.LogTimestamp.Year,
        Month = l.LogTimestamp.Month,
        Day = l.LogTimestamp.Day,
        Hour = l.LogTimestamp.Hour,
        Minute = (l.LogTimestamp.Minute / intervalInMinutes) * intervalInMinutes,
    })
    .Select(g => new LogsOccurence()
    {
        StartingDatetime = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day, g.Key.Hour, g.Key.Minute, 0),
        Frequency = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Following query fails:

> An exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: could not execute query
>
> Inner exception: Column 'dbo.Log.LogTimestamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Generated select statement is:

```
select 
    datepart(year, Log0_.LogTimestamp) as col_0_0_
    , datepart(month, Log0_.LogTimestamp) as col_1_0_
    , datepart(day, Log0_.LogTimestamp) as col_2_0_
    , datepart(hour, Log0_.LogTimestamp) as col_3_0_
    , datepart(minute, Log0_.LogTimestamp) as col_4_0_
    , cast(count(*) as INT) as col_5_0_
from 
    dbo.[Log] Log0_
group by 
    datepart(year, Log0_.LogTimestamp)
    , datepart(month, Log0_.LogTimestamp)
    , datepart(day, Log0_.LogTimestamp)
    , datepart(hour, Log0_.LogTimestamp)
    , datepart(minute, Log0_.LogTimestamp)/@p0*@p1
Name:p1 - Value:30  Name:p2 - Value:30
```

1. Operator precedence / order is wrong in `groupby` clause

   ```
   datepart(minute, Log0_.LogTimestamp) / @p0 * @p1
   ```
2. Select part for minutes is different than group part for minutes - select fails

What is wrong with my Linq, and how to write correct one?

I am using NHibernate build 4.0.4.GA.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. I've tested your Linq query using LinqToSql (Entity Framework) and it worked fine. I also looked at the NHibernate JIRA issue tracker (https://nhibernate.jira.com) for open bugs, but no one seems to match this one. So, I think it is a unreported bug.

Answer (score 0):

> **Operator precedence / order is wrong in groupby clause**

The operator precedence looks correct to me.  Multiplication and division have the same level of precedence, in both [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) and [T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx).  Thus...

```
datepart(minute, Log0_.LogTimestamp) / @p0 * @p1
```

... is equivalent to...

```
(datepart(minute, Log0_.LogTimestamp) / @p0) * @p1
```

---

> **Select part for minutes is different than group part for minutes - select fails.**

It is also different in the LINQ query.  Since the `GroupBy` has...

```
Minute = (l.LogTimestamp.Minute / intervalInMinutes) * intervalInMinutes,
```

..., the `Select` should also have...

```
g.Key.Minute / intervalInMinutes * intervalInMinutes
```

That might possibly fix it.